# Listen to a custom chaincode event in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: events, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After using `SetEvent()` in the chaincode, how is possible to test it? 
Does exist some working example?

Answer (score 4):

You could create an application which is listening on the chaincode event.

I suggest you to have a look at the "Chaincode event listener" section of this link, which is the official Hyperledger Fabric Nodejs SDK.

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-events.html

First is necessary to configure the client correctly.
Once it has been configured:

```
//... client configuration

var channel = fabric_client.getChannel();
var eventHub = channel.getChannelEventHubsForOrg(<NAME OF YOUR ORG>)[0];

eventHub.connect(true);
eventHub.registerChaincodeEvent(CHAINCODE_ID,EVENT_NAME,
    (event, block_num, txnid, status)=>{
        console.log('Successfully got a chaincode event with transid:'+ txnid + ' with status:'+status);
        console.log('Successfully received the chaincode event on block number '+ block_num);
        console.log(event);
    },
    (error)=>{
        console.log('Failed to receive the chaincode event ::'+error);
    }
);
```

Comment: I already went that way. It is exactly what is not working for me. Do you have a working example?

Comment: Thank you, I will test it soon. I already did something similar but I did not set the organization, let’s see if that was the problem.

Comment: unfortunately is still not possible to get the payload from the event. event.payload is undefined...

Comment: The connection must be set up to receive full blocks.
eventHub.connect(true);

Comment: I am not getting the payload in listener :| can you please share your `setEvent` code as well